# Casting char buffer to function pointer

Tags: c++, casting

I recently found out that you can inject machine code in a buffer, at run-time, cast it to a function pointer and then call it to execute the instructions in the buffer. It looks something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "\xB8\x04\x00\x00\x00\xC3";
    auto func = (int(*)())buffer;
    func();

    return 0;
}
```

Now what if i don't want to pay for the function call at run-time, in other words i want to treat the buffer as an `inline` function.

My first naive attempt to achieve this was to declare both the `buffer` and the `func` as `constexpr` and replace the c-style cast with `static_cast`, although this doesn't seem to work, because it's an invalid cast according to gcc.
Tried `reinterpret_cast` too, but that can't be evaluated at compile-time apparently

Any ideas would be welcome, if is possible to achieve this at all.

Comment: That call is indeed possible on certain architectures, and that is indeed an example of undefined behavior. There is no way this can be treated as inline function, though. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @SergeyA I'm trying to tie the assembly code to c++ templates. With some template metaprogramming magic it is possible to generate the actual instruction buffer at compile time and i need that buffer to be altered/depend on some template arguments.
Basically to create a form of template assembly.

Comment: Imagine that you are a compiler. What would you do with this program? Can you show a sequence of steps?

Comment: @Lorand, still unclear why do you need to generate the buffer at compile time instead of just writing normal C++ code? Perhaps a more specific MCVE could help?

Comment: @n.m. Now that i think about it, inlining a function means that it's body is copied on it's call site. For me this would mean that the content of the buffer would have to be copied there. And doing all this in a way that the compiler believe it is actually valid code.

Comment: @Lorand there multiple ways to emit assembly (see inline __asm for example) in C/C++ without resorting to ugly UB hacks.

Comment: @DanM. I'm looking specifically for methods that allow me to intermix assembly with c++ templates

Comment: @Lorand depends on what and how exactly you'd like to intermix them. See for some examples/pointers: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: @SergeyA The buffer is actually known at compile time, the question is how to trick the compiler in believing that it is an inline function, or a sequence of instructions or anything that can be exeecuted, wihtout the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Inlining a function doesn't involve taking its assembly code and inserting it as is at the call site.

Comment: @Lorand you still didn't answer 'why'. Why do you want to generate ASM instead of writing C++ code? The template metaprogramming is exactly a technique to generate code, and compiler usually does a better job than you. I could explain why inlining is not possible, or I can try to give you an answer for the actual problem.

Comment: @SergeyA Indeed the compilers do a magnificent job 99% of the time, but i want to make a highly optimized gemm (blas msatrix matrix multiplication) implementation and i would like to fine-tune the code using assembly instructions

Comment: This is how malicious code work. Is that your intention?

Comment: If you need to use inline assembly, go ahead and use it. There is a [construct in C++ dedicated to it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline assembly code can be injected in a C++ function with an [asm declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm). This construct is conditionally supported and implementation defined.

In most implementations, the asm declaration expects some form of symbolic assembly language rather than binary object code.

Here's an example of using the `asm` declaration construct with GCC on x86.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int nontype>
int add(int operand)
{
    int sum;

    asm ("movl %1, %0\n\t"
         "addl %2, %0"
         : "=r" (sum)
         : "r" (operand), "r" (nontype)
         : "0");

    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add<42>(6) << "\n";
}
```

This prints 48 as expected.

Note that gcc's version of `asm` is quite powerful, and its syntax has to go beyond what the standard specifies in order to support its many features. Other implementations may or may not offer such flexibility (or indeed offer anything at all — the construct is conditionally supported).

Casting between function pointers and data pointers is undefined behaviour in C++. Implementations may do whatever they want with it. I would guess that exploiting this particular form of UB to duplicate perfectly good asm declaration functionality would be rather low on most implementers' to-do lists.

Comment: Sadly, the asm declaration supported by certain compilers don't let me to generate asm at compile time, i.e. placing a non-type template parameter in an instruction as an immediate value

Comment: @Lorand I feel your pain. Good luck.

Comment: @Lorand added an example.